# How can I change or shut off a screensaver setting without using Gnome

Tags: gnome, screensaver

I set a screensaver that freezes my computer and because changing the screensaver using the Gnome desktop displays the screensaver it locks up my computer before I can make the change.

I would prefer to set the screensaver off.

Answer (score 6):

Using the graphical tool GConf Editor:

1. Run the command `gconf-editor` from a terminal or  the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> dialog.
2. Navigate to *apps ➜ gnome-screensaver*.
3. Uncheck the `idle_activation_enabled` setting to stop the screensaver from activating automatically.
4. If you want to set the screensaver theme to *Blank screen*, right click on the `themes` item and click *Unset Key*.

   [image]

---

From the command line:

- Disable the screensaver from automatically running when the computer is idle:

  ```
  gconftool --set --type=bool /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled False
  ```
- Set the screensaver theme to *Blank screen*:

  ```
  gconftool --unset /apps/gnome-screensaver/themes
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I'll learn Ubuntu yet!